# discord.js Check if message author id is in the database?

Tags: mysql, discord.js

I have MySQL database(I literally don't know anything about databases, only some basics) for my bot and I have TABLE where I want to store members levels and XP but I need to check first if that member id isn't already in the database so if he isn't in the database he will be added to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query xp by `SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id=?` (instead of ?, add the id by code). And when the query = null, undefinied or {} (idk what exactly mysql returns), the user is not in database.